# Convert string special characters

Tags: php, string, character-encoding

I have this kind of text:

```
/&gt; 23 visível (diagonal)&lt;br /&gt; Energy Star&lt;br /&gt;
```

I want to convert it to a real texto to show on browser....

I've tried htmlentities method, but i'm getting this:

```
 23 visÃƒÂ­vel (diagonal)
 Energy Star
```

And i should get:

```
visível (diagonal)
Energy Star
```

Comment: Which encoding does your original string have?

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: Everyone suggests `utf-8` or `htmlentities`. But your original string has no reserved characters, as everything has already been converted to a `htmlentity`, leaving only just characters. It seems to me you want to strip `htmlentitied` characters...have i lost the plot, what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result looks like **utf8** for me... 
You could try with an additional

```
utf8_decode( ... ).
```

But the real answer is to change the default encoding header to utf8 in apache
or with

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

php by default should use utf-8 (see php.net)

Comment: +1 for @deceze  for the link it's a good advise to do some reading...

Comment: Work for me but i need to use both urf8_decode and header.... what about save on database? How i can do to save with the right characters??

Answer (score 0):

To display corectly utf-8 characters, add this code at the beginning of your php script:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

And this code in html5 document:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: Work for me but i need to use both urf8_decode and header.... what about save on database? How i can do to save with the right characters??